# How to call multiple controller actions into the single page tabs in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have three `models, controllers` and `views`.

```
1. package
2. source
3. measure
```

Everything has separate `forms`. I created a `controller` and `view` called `scenario` and created three `tabs(Package, Source and Measure)` in the `scenario` page.

I need to `render` the `three tabs` to call each one of the above `controller` and `views` like `Package` should do the action of `create, edit, update and destroy of Packages controller` and vice-verse.

How should i call those three different `controller` actions in the `Scenario` page? I want all the three into the single page and work within their `tabs`.

What shall i include in the index, new, create, edit and update methods in Scenario controller? Do i need to create all the view files for scenario too?

Any help would be more appreciated.

P.S. I tested all the three are working fine with their separate pages.

Answer (score 0):

best to use ajax calls and render the view templates within the respective tab with js/erb template. e.g.,

show.js.erb

```
$('<%= @selector %>').html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:action => :show)) %>");
```

if you wanna use this same ajax call to render show action elsewhere, then send a selector as a request param depending on which page you are on: e.g., when you are on the scenario page and the div id for package tab is say 'package-tab', then send selector `'#package-tab'` as param and set @selector to this in your controller. with this you can control from the request which dom-element is refreshed by the ajax call.

does this answer the question?

Comment: my specific question is what shall i include in the scenario controller?

Comment: nothing really, you better just have a scenario template which renders the 3 tabs with ajax callbacks to respective controller actions you want to display initially

Comment: I updated the question so please read again. I just have index page in the scenario view and index method in my scenario controller.

Comment: i answered your question more than exhaustively i feel. if not try explain better :)